# Can diamond blade cut aluminum and brass rods?

Tags: powertools, aluminum, metal-cutting

As the question is self explanatory, I want to know can I diamond blade cut aluminum and brass rods? I have a 7" diamond blade (circular) but I cannot find the manufacturer's recommendations on this. If someone can help.
If in case, it is not good to cut al and brass rods with diamond blades, please also suggest what kind of blades can I buy for the same. Thanks. [image: Diamond blade]

Comment: Metal cutting blades can usually be used to cut most metals.  They also do a nice on plexiglass.

Comment: Brass and aluminum are both relatively soft metals.  So you don't have to go to the expense of a diamond blade to cut those materials.  A good bi-metallic blade will work just fine.  The blade material (or the cutting edge/teeth) just needs to be harder than the material you're trying to cut.

Comment: @crip659 thank you, I will look at metal cutting blades. What do you mean by plexiglass? Is plexiglass also a cutting blade?

Comment: @SteveSh, thanks,will look for bi-metallic blade.

Comment: @GaganBatra Plexiglass is not a cutting blade. It is clear plastic sold in sheets and metal cutting blades do a nice job cutting Plexiglass.

Comment: I would buy a regular metal cutting blade and not expose a valuable diamond blade to wear and tear , and possible mishap.

Comment: The diamond blade probably _can_ be used to cut aluminum and/or brass for a few cuts, but it probably isn't the best blade to use. It might ruin the blade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My question has been answered in comments, providing a summary of it:
As @GregNickoloff and @blacksmith37 mentioned that it might be possible for a few cuts but it would probably ruin the blade (wear and tear of diamond plate), so it is better not to use it. Also a side note, the shown blade is supposedly only to be used for tile cutting or similar materials.
As a solution, @crisp659, @SteveSh and others have suggested to use a metal cutting blade or a bi-metallic blade.

Comment: Nice job of gathering all the "Answers in comments" into an actual answer! Thanks for doing so.